# ion-button in ionic v4 the text is uppercase

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a problem with `ion-button` in *ionic v4*
If I write in my app

```
<ion-button>Hi</ion-button>
```

[image: Erro upercase]

And run the application, the app show the button with te text in uppercase
I need the buttons to be shown with the text as I wrote it. Please

Answer (score 42):

In ionic-5, in `theme/variables.css`, you could add the following

```
ion-button {
 text-transform: none;
}
```

This would apply for the entire app.  Also refer [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17470#issuecomment-462814964) github issue comment.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use **`text-capitalize`**, for every *first* words in UperCase

```
<span text-capitalize>hi</span>
```

[image]

or ***`text-transform`***, for *normal* text

```
<span style="text-transform:none!important;">Hi Hi</span>
```

[image]

For more examples and other utilities check this [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities/), you'll like!

Answer (score 8):

You can solve it by adding just inline css as following :

```
<ion-button style="text-transform:none">Your Text</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use **mode="ios"**. Tested on ionic 5 :

```
<ion-button mode="ios">Your Text</ion-button>
```

Comment: can you set this somewhere globally ?

Answer (score 4):

You can add this style in the global.scss
`ion-button { text-transform: none; }`
I have tested this code and it works well